# explanation of isValid() in QSqlQuery

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qsqlquery

Hi i m unable to understand the explanation of isValid method of QSqlQuery in Qt.

The query always returns False for isValid()

and true for next(),first() etc

I checked for lastErrors as well if any, none were there

I m new to qt , can anyone explain me what is meant by

```
bool QSqlQuery::isValid () const

Returns true if the query is currently positioned on a valid record; otherwise returns false.
```

Code --

```
query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
query.exec_("select * from test.PG_Details where PG_Id = 1")

print("Bool->",query.isValid())     // Return FALSE
print("Next->",query.next())        // Returns TRUE
print("LE->",query.lastError().text())     //Returns Blank
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation does not explain the concept correctly, but if we review the [source code](https://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/master/src/sql/kernel/qsqlquery.cpp#L758):

```
bool QSqlQuery::isValid() const
{
    return d->sqlResult->isValid();
}
```

`d->sqlResult` is a `QSqlResult`, so if we check the docs of the [`isValid()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlresult.html#isValid) method of [`QSqlResult`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlresult.html):

> **bool QSqlResult::isValid() const**
>
> Returns true if the result is positioned on a valid record (that is,
>   the result is not positioned before the first or after the last
>   record); otherwise returns false.

And there is clearly understood what returns `QSqlQuery::isValid()`, will return false in 2 cases, the first is when data has not yet been requested for the result, and the second when there is no data.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtSql

def createConnection():
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName(":memory:")
    if not db.open():
        return False

    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    query.exec_("create table PG_Details (PG_Id int, firstname varchar(20), lastname varchar(20))")

    query.exec_("insert into PG_Details values(1, 'Danny', 'Young')")
    query.exec_("insert into PG_Details values(2, 'Christine', 'Holand')")
    query.exec_("insert into PG_Details values(1, 'Lars', 'Gordon')")
    query.exec_("insert into PG_Details values(2, 'Roberto', 'Robitaille')")
    query.exec_("insert into PG_Details values(1, 'Maria', 'Papadopoulos')")

    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not createConnection():
        sys.exit(-1)

    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()

    if not query.exec_("select * from PG_Details where PG_Id = 1"):
        print("Error: ", query.lastError().text())

    print("isValid: ", query.isValid(), "before")

    while query.next():
        res = query.value(0)
        print("isValid: ", query.isValid())

    print("isValid: ", query.isValid(), "after")
```

Results:

```
isValid:  False before
isValid:  True
isValid:  True
isValid:  True
isValid:  False after
```

It is clear that before requesting data, in this example we use `query.value(0)`, it is False, it is True while there is data, and it is False again when there is no data.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, is there a way to check if the query contains results without try and except block.

is there a native function provided by QSqlQuery to check this

Comment: @VaibhavSharma I do not use try, except. What do you mean by that?

Comment: I meant that , the reason to use isValid was to check if the query return with at-least one row.

by try and except I meant , that executing the query and returning the result set under the try block if it contains any value else it can be initialised to 0

Comment: @VaibhavSharma You can use size(), but if this is not supported by all the databases, for example QSQLITE does not support it.

Comment: @Edwin Christian - I guess next would be a better way to check this as if it returns False then the result set does not contain any records, your thoughts on this

Comment: @VaibhavSharma 
Note that if you use next() you must ask for the data since if you call next () again after the first data is discarded. I recommend you try code to understand. The example I show is the typical form. Another way is to use SQL with the "count" query.

Comment: @Edwin - Thank you for your assistance, advise taken , I m new to programming and learning it with mistakes

Comment: I'm very confused with the value(0), because I didn't call `query.next()` at all... without it, it always returns None..., I was about to put question... thanks.